# Would this question about lowering the barrier to entry on choosing spells be closed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I'm about to kick off a second D&D 5e campaign for a set of friends interested in trying D&D for the first time. They've got nearly zero experience with the game, and we're hitting some hurdles I didn't expect.

One of these is that two of them are playing classes with spells, and they've ended up with total choice paralysis. Both of them are terrified of choosing the "wrong" spells and keep changing their minds on a practically minute-to-minute basis. (Seriously, the amount of texts I've gotten from each of them...) But it's hard to explain what the spells do or how useful they'll be when your audience has no personal experience with the game.

TL:DR; I'd like to make choosing spells more newbie-friendly, but I don't know how.

However that ^^^ question (if actually phrased as a question) strikes me as something that might get closed as too broad, or maybe subjective. Are my instincts right? Can I phrase it differently to make it RPGse acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that might work. Your problem is a people one — introducing new players to an unknown game. That's the sort of thing that's amenable to other people saying “hey! I've been there exactly before. Here's what worked and what didn't when I handled it.”

The thing a question like this needs to survive is to fend off the people who want to answer “I think that you should…” who have no experience with this problem. When a question like this gets a lot of that kind of answer it suggests that the question itself is somehow attracting them, and then it gets closed as Primarily Opinion-Based.

So with that in mind, you can craft the question carefully to make sure those kinds of answers are **obviously** off topic early in the question. That makes it more likely for people who just have an opinion to notice and rethink their desire to spill their untested impulse thoughts onto the site. Something like…

> **I could really use some advice from someone with experience with new players dealing with D&D spell analysis paralysis.**
>
> I'm about to kick off a second D&D 5e campaign for a set of friends interested in trying D&D for the first time. They've got nearly zero experience with the game, and we're hitting some hurdles I didn't expect.
>   …